# Change/push-one place next all input value onchange current input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic form with many inputs having different values, when any input is changed i want next values to shift down one place so that the value that is changed becomes next value and so on.

Html

```
<form name="top-download-update-edit">
<input name="v1" type="text" value="value1" />
<input name="v2" type="text" value="value2" />
<input name="v3" type="text" value="value3" />
<input name="v4" type="text" value="value4" />
<input name="v5" type="text" value="value5" />
</form>
```

Say input v2 is changed to value6 like

```
<input name="v2" type="text" value="value6" />
```

Now i want next all value to shift one place down like this.

```
<input name="v1" type="text" value="value1" />
<input name="v2" type="text" value="value6" />
<input name="v3" type="text" value="value2" />
<input name="v4" type="text" value="value3" />
<input name="v5" type="text" value="value4" />
```

I am trying this way

```
$('#nav').on('change', 'form[name=update] input', function(){
    var input = $(this).val();
    $(this).next('input').val(input);
    //and some thing here to shift all next values one place.
});
```

This does nothing.
Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks.

**Update**

My actual codes.

update.php

```
<div id="update">

<form name="update" action="update-edit.php" method="post">

  <?php $i=1; while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):?>
  <label><?php echo $i.'. ' ?><input name="v<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" value="<?php  echo $row['title'] ?>" /></label>
  <?php $i++; endwhile;?>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>

</div>
```

jquery

```
$.post('../update.php',{value:value},function(data){
    $('#center-container').html(data);

    var v1 = $('input[name=v1]').val();
    var v2 = $('input[name=v2]').val();
    var v3 = $('input[name=v3]').val();
    var v4 = $('input[name=v4]').val();
    var v5 = $('input[name=v5]').val();
    var v6 = $('input[name=v6]').val();

    $("form[name=update]").data("values", {"v1": v1, "v2": v1, "v3": v3, "v4": v4, "v5": v5, "v6": v6});

    $('form[name=update] input').change(function(){
        var form = $(this).parent().parent();
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        form.find('input').each(function() {
            var thisName = $(this).attr('name');
            var prevName = $(this).parent().prev('label').children('input').attr('name');
            if($(this).attr('name') > name){
                $(this).val(form.data('values')[prevName]);
            }
        });
        form.find('input').each(function() {
            form.data('values')[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        });
    });     


});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what are you trying to accomplish. What happens if "v2" is changed to "v3"? Is there an alphabetical order?

Comment: @Aioros there is no alphabetical order, `if v2=v3, then v3=v2, v4=v3 so on`, just push value one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I would do something like this: since in the `.change()` function you have no way to know the previous value of the `input`, you need to store current values somewhere in order to shift everything. You can use the `.data()` function.

```
$("form[name=update]").data("values", {"v1": "value1", "v2": "value2", "v3": "value3", "v4": "value4", "v5": "value5"});
$("form[name=update] input").change(function(){
    var form = $(this).parent();
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    form.find("[name="+name+"] ~ input").each(function() {
        var thisName = $(this).attr("name");
        var prevName = $(this).prev("input").attr("name");
        $(this).val(form.data("values")[prevName]);
    });
    form.find("input").each(function() {
        form.data("values")[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

This basically means that each time you change an input value you find all the next input "siblings" (that's the `~` css selector) and replace their values with the old ones you stored. After this, of course, you update the stored data. By the way, it would probably be easier to use `id`s instead of name attributes to identify your elements.

You can find a [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jy6tt/).

Comment: Thank you so much its working in your example, but i get it to work with some modification, please see the update and suggest if this is the proper way of doing this.

Comment: I suppose it wasn't working because of the different tag structure (the label tags, basically), which messed up the "siblings" CSS selector and the .prev() function. I was actually wondering how did you fix it :)

Comment: Well, yes, it's ok. The only drawback is that you compare the name attributes alphabetically to determine which comes first. This could be impossible if you happened to have different kinds of names (in that case, you could maybe loop through the inputs and do nothing until you find the changed one, and then start another loop from there with the instructions needed).

Comment: Thanks, i got it working because name has numeric values to compare.

Comment: are you there i need to ask one think.

Comment: Well, yes, but let's try not to turn this into a chat :D What's the question?

Comment: i need to ask how can i found if a value entered already exist in .data() function. i am trying this way `if($(this).val() == form.data('values')[name]){alert('duplicate value');}` but it does notthing.

Comment: Well, it depends on where and when you do that check. It seems to me that you're checking if the new value is equal to the stored one. If you want to search in the whole `values` array you might use [`.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/). If you need to, try and open a new question rather than discussing it here.

Comment: yes i want to check this way, so `.inArray()` can find data in `.data()`.

Comment: Got it working this way, when onchange get value `var value_check = $(this).val();` and then check value when in .each() function `if(value_check == form.data('values')[thisName]){alert('duplicate value');}`.